# How to Fix the "Device is not Certified by Google" Error on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-source

I built Android image from AOSP then run it on emulator. I downloaded Google's applications from https://opengapps.org/ then installed them onto emulator. But when open GoogleMap application, i encountered error as below image.
How can i workaround this error ? I just wanna run GoogleMap on my emulator for testing purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should read error messages, because it clearly reads:

> To use Google apps and services with a custom ROM, **register this device**.
>   Learn more at [g.co/AndroidDeviceRegistration](https://www.google.com/android/uncertified/).

Comment: I tried to do follow g.co/AndroidDeviceRegistration but when I run the second command, result is "not found"

Comment: On my Android 6 Google Play x86 emulator, it says "adbd cannot run as root in production builds" for `adb root` command